# i>>=1 more efficient than i/2

Tags: java, performance

I recently programmed a small application and there I needed to divide many, many numbers by 2. At first I just used the line `i/2;` but a friend of mine said i could just use the operator `i>>=1` which produces the same numbers. Just for fun we meassured the time it took to compute and we found out that the i>>=1 method was on average 15% (30ms improvement) faster. (`i` is an int)

Why is that so? I just changed one operater nothing else.

Comment: I'd say you're micro optimizing. You can trust JIT optimisations.

Comment: On machine code level: bit shift is a relatively simple operation; multiplication is done more or less as you learned at school, for every bit 1 the other parameter shifted and added to a result.